# Encrypting Ansible Playbook .pem private key with ansible-vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, pem

Is there any way to encrypt --private-key with ansible-vault and use it encrypted with Ansible Playbook ansible-playbook command (or inside Playbook)?

I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
$ ansible-vault create encrypted_ssh_key.pem --vault-password-file vault_password_file
```

(pasted my SSH private key into it)

```
$ ansible-playbook ansible_playbook -i inventory/ec2.py \
    -e ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu \
    -e ansible_user=ubuntu \
    --private-key=encrypted_ssh_key.pem \
    --vault-password-file vault_password_file
```

It's always asking me for a passphrase and even after I enter it (the one from vault_password_file) it doesn't accept it. I can login to EC2 instance without any problems by using that private key.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `ssh-keygen` encrypts the private key already. There is no need to encrypt it with `ansible-vault`. Use `ssh-agent` instead of writing the password of your ssh key into a clear text file.

Comment: Suppose you are using AWS EC2 which generates private key for you, and you want to encrypt it by using ansible-vault, as the whole ansible playbook file is encrypted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you are taking a wrong approach.

What you need is to create a passphrase for the key, not encrypt the key with Ansible Vault.

```
openssl rsa -in ssh_key.pem -out encrypted_ssh_key.pem
```

Give it a passphrase and provide that passphrase every time you run it (or use some agent which would cache the password for you):

```
ansible-playbook ansible_playbook -i inventory/ec2.py \
    -e ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu \
    -e ansible_user=ubuntu \
    --private-key=encrypted_ssh_key.pem
```